# calculate difference between two rows in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following two tables -

```
Table1

TR1 TR2
1   10
2   15
3   20

Table2

TC1 TC2
10  100
15  150
20  200

select count(*) from table1, table2 where table1.tr2 = table2.tc1 and table1.tr1 > 1 and table1.tr2 in (select table2.tc1 from table2 where table2.tc1 > 10)

select count(*) from table1, table2 where table1.tr2 = table2.tc1 and table1.tr1 > 1 and table1.tr1 < 5 and table1.tr2 in (select table2.tc1 from table2 where table2.tc1 > 10)
```

2nd query will return a subset of the first query, I want to find the difference in count(*)s given by the two queries. How do I go about it?

Comment: Where is the link between the rows you want to difference in your result set? Also, explisit joins (join ... on) has been here since 2000, so it should be about time to start using it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do

```
select (select count(*) ...) - (select count(*) ...);
```

But as your queries are so similar, you can merge the queries instead:

```
select
  count(*) - sum(t1.tr1 < 5)
from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on t1.tr2 = t2.tc1 
where t1.tr1 > 1
and t1.tr2 > 10;
```

I've changed your comma-separated join to a proper ANSI join. Your join syntax was made redundant in 1992. You shouldn't use it anymore.

I've replaced your `IN` clause with a simple `t1.tr2 > 10`, because you are already joining on `t1.tr2 = t2.tc1`.

Comment: Unrelated to this question, but was curious, how do we calculate difference when each subquery returns multiple rows i.e with count(*), I return one more row from the inner subquery but I don't want that in difference?

Comment: If there were several rows, lets say the order count per product, you'd join the two results on the relating attribute, i.e. the product here, so you'd get the differences per product.

Answer (score 0):

you can do the a diff this way

```
 select (
      select count(*) 
      from table1, table2 
      where table1.tr2 = table2.tc1 
      and table1.tr1 > 1 
      and table1.tr2 in (select table2.tc1 from table2 where table2.tc1 > 10)
  ) - (
      select count(*) 
      from table1, table2 
      where table1.tr2 = table2.tc1
      and table1.tr1 > 1 
      and table1.tr1 < 5 
      and table1.tr2 in (select table2.tc1 from table2 where table2.tc1 > 10)
  )  as my_diff
from dual;
```

Comment: sql fiddle for this?